# Display listbox according to current Application.UserName

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a code here derived from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76989379/excel-listbox-show-entries-entered-in-the-current-date-only) that displays listbox correctly in the current date. If I have a column B that stores different usernames, I want to insert this in the code:

> If current username (Application.UserName) in the active form is equal to one of the names in column
> B then filter entries today for that username only

Current output:

> Listbox is filtered in current date using the code below

Desired output

> The same Listbox is filtered in the current date and current username using the code below with an additional code for username filtering

Update

This is the raw data:

```
Username       ||Date            ||Start Time    ||Color

Murray, Leo W  ||9/24/2023       ||9:08:28 AM    ||white

Murray, Leo W  ||9/24/2023       ||9:10:06 AM    ||black

Murray, Leo W  ||9/24/2023       ||9:12:09 AM    ||gray

Murray, Leo W  ||9/24/2023       ||9:13:13 AM    ||blue

Murray, Leo W  ||9/24/2023       ||5:34:03 AM    ||yellow

Smith, Pia Y   ||9/24/2023       ||6:02:59 AM    ||green

Smith, Pia Y   ||9/24/2023       ||6:05:57 AM    ||red

McGrath, Sam O ||9/24/2023       ||6:09:30 AM    ||brown

McGrath, Sam O ||9/24/2023       ||6:13:59 AM    ||white

McGrath, Sam O ||9/24/2023       ||6:17:29 AM    ||green

McGrath, Sam O ||9/24/2023       ||6:38:55 AM    ||white

McGrath, Sam O ||9/24/2023       ||6:41:07 AM    ||gray

Blake, Gary K  ||9/24/2023       ||6:42:03 AM    ||red

Blake, Gary K  ||9/24/2023       ||6:43:31 AM    ||rare white

Blake, Gary K  ||9/24/2023       ||6:43:31 AM    ||rare white

Blake, Gary K  ||9/24/2023       ||8:52:26 AM    ||trial

McGrath, Sam O ||9/24/2023       ||7:59:33 PM    ||red
```

Image of raw data:
[image: image of raw data]

Updated derived code including the answer of Taller below:

```
Private Sub defineConstants()
     ' Define constants.
Const SRC_SHEET As String = "ExcelEntryDB"
Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "B1" ‘’’*************changed from C1 to B1
Const DST_SHEET As String = "ExcelEntryDB" ' !!!
Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "K1" ' !!! ‘’’’*************changed from H1 to K1
Const DST_COLUMN_FORMATS As String = "mm\/dd\/yyyy;hh:mm:ss AM/PM;@"
Const DST_COLUMN_FORMATS_DELIMITER As String = ";"
Const LBX_COLUMN_WIDTHS As String = "75;75;75;75"
Const USER_COLUMN As Long = 1 ‘’****************from the answer below
Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 2
Const DST_SORT_COLUMN As Long = 3
Dim dSortOrder As XlSortOrder: dSortOrder = xlDescending
'Dim CriteriaDate As Date: CriteriaDate = Date - (13 / 24) ' =TODAY()
Dim CriteriaDate As Date: CriteriaDate = Format(Date - (13 / 24), "mm/dd/yyyy")
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
' Write the source data to the source array.
Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Split(LBX_COLUMN_WIDTHS, ";")) + 1
Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).Resize(, cCount)
Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
With hrg.Offset(1)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox "No data in worksheet.", vbCritical
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnCount = cCount
            .ColumnHeads = True
            .ColumnWidths = LBX_COLUMN_WIDTHS
            '.RowSource = ddrg.Address(External:=True)
        End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 2
       Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
End With
   ' Check if the date criterion was found.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = srg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN)
    Dim drCount As Long:
    drCount = Application.CountIf(crg, CriteriaDate)
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sData(): sData = Union(hrg, srg).Value
    ' Return the headers and matching rows in the destination array.
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount + 1, 1 To cCount)
    Dim sValue, sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long, WriteRow As Boolean
    Dim sUser As String '''''''''''''''''''''**from the answer
For sr = 1 To srCount
        If sr = 1 Then ' headers
            WriteRow = True
        Else ' data rows
            sValue = sData(sr, CRITERIA_COLUMN)
            sUser = sData(sr, USER_COLUMN) ‘’****************from the answer below
            If IsDate(sValue) Then
                If sValue = CriteriaDate And sUser = "McGrath, Sam O" Then ‘’****************from the answer below
                'If sValue = CriteriaDate Then
                    WriteRow = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If WriteRow Then
            WriteRow = False
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
      ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(dr, cCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear


    ' Sort and format the destination data range.
         If dr = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Nothing"
        End If
        ' Reference the destination data range (no headers).
        Dim ddrg As Range: Set ddrg = drg.Resize(dr - 1).Offset(1)
' Sort the data range.
    If DST_SORT_COLUMN >= 1 And DST_SORT_COLUMN <= cCount Then
        ddrg.Sort ddrg.Columns(DST_SORT_COLUMN), dSortOrder, , , , , , xlNo
    End If
    ' Write the formats to a string array.
    Dim dcFormats() As String:
    dcFormats = Split(DST_COLUMN_FORMATS, DST_COLUMN_FORMATS_DELIMITER)
    ' Apply the formats to each column of the data range.
    For c = 0 To UBound(dcFormats)
        ddrg.Columns(c + 1).NumberFormat = dcFormats(c)
    Next c
    ' Tie the row source of the listbox to the destination data range.
    ' The headers are automatically recognized.
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = cCount
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = LBX_COLUMN_WIDTHS
        .RowSource = ddrg.Address(External:=True)
    End With
End Sub
```

It is getting the result for the declared username as per answer (in this case for McGrath) except that the date changed to 12:00:00 AM and Time became decimals in the result:

Excel result
[image: excel result]

Listbox result
[image: listbox result]

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated code (marked with **) assumes user name is in column 3. Please update as needed.

```vb
Const USER_COLUMN As Long = 3  ' ** Update as needed
Dim sUser as String ' **
For sr = 1 To srCount
    If sr = 1 Then ' headers
        WriteRow = True
    Else ' data rows
        sValue = sData(sr, CRITERIA_COLUMN)
        sUser = sData(sr, USER_COLUMN) ' **
        If IsDate(sValue) Then
            If sValue = CriteriaDate AND sUser=Application.UserName Then ' **
                WriteRow = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If WriteRow Then
        WriteRow = False
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
        Next c
    End If
Next sr
```

Set date/time format before loading listbox

```
    dws.Columns("L:L").NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy"
    dws.Columns("M:M").NumberFormatLocal = "h:mm:ss AM/PM;@"
```

Comment: Okay let me try brb

Comment: Hi i updated the post with the raw data. TY

Comment: You can set date/time format before loadint listbox. I have uploade a code snippet.

Comment: Checking.be right back

Comment: This is so great, thank you!!!!